# use for loop to add downloading sections to a powershell script

Tags: powershell, for-loop, batch-file, download, echo

I want to construct a powershell script that downloads a specific set of files. This set will change periodically, so a `for` loop is the cleanest way to update the process.

The URLs for each file update on a daily basis with both the date and a unique serial number, but I already have a process in place for extracting that info and saving it to a file.  I also have a method for constructing a PS script to download a specific file from such a URL:

```
set /p file_info=<"<path to file with info>"
set file_dir=<known page directories>
set DL=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\test.ps1

echo $url = "http://<domain>.com/%file_dir%/%file_info%" > "%DL%"
echo $output = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\%file_info%" >> "%DL%"
echo (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output) >> "%DL%"
```

I can also loop additions to a PS script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p obj=<"<path to file with list of objects>"
set /p file_info=<"<path to file with info>"
set DL=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\test.ps1

:: restarting PS script
echo #new > "%DL%"

for %%f in (%obj%) do (
set a=%%f
echo !a!!file_info! >> "!DL!"
)
```

However, when I replace `echo !a!!file_info! >> "!DL!"` with the `echo` lines from the first script (adapted in the same fashion), the PS script is no longer updated with the looped content (note that I now use the PS username to avoid any issues with delayed expansion):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p obj=<"<path to file with list of objects>"
set /p file_info=<"<path to file with info>"
set file_dir=<known page directories>
set DL=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\test.ps1

:: restarting PS script
echo #new > "%DL%"

for %%f in (%obj%) do (
set a=%%f
echo $url = "http://<domain>.com/!file_dir!/!a!/!file_info!" >> "!DL!"
echo $output = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\!file_info!" >> "!DL!"
echo (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output) >> "!DL!"
)

::alternative that doesn't work either:

for %%f in (%obj%) do (
set a=%%f
call echo $url = "http://<domain>.com/!file_dir!/!a!/!file_info!" >> "!DL!"
call echo $output = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\!file_info!" >> "!DL!"
call echo (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output) >> "!DL!"
)
```

Why are there issues using a `for` loop to add URL download sections to a PS script?  Is there a way to avoid these issues?

Comment: I do not understand why you're even using `set a=%%f`, there's no reason not to use `%%f` directly. Also in your delayed expansion versions, as the variables `file_dir` and `file_info` are defined only once outside of any code block, they  do not need to be expanded at run time, so should really remain as standard variables, `%file_dir%`, and `%file_info%`.

Comment: @Compo that was how I originally constructed the script, but I've had similar issues in the past that were resolved with delayed expansion, so I thought it was necessary here too.  thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that your `echo`ed closing parentheses are prematurely closing the `for` loop parentheses. In my example below, I've escaped those with carets, `^`.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set /P "obj=" 0< "<path to file with list of objects>"
Set /P "file_info=" 0< "<path to file with info>"
Set "file_dir=<known page directories>"
Set "DL=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\test.ps1"

(   For %%G In (%obj%) Do (
        Echo $url = "http://<domain>.com/%file_dir%/%%G/%file_info%"
        Echo $output = "C:\Users\$Env:UserName\Downloads\%file_info%"
        Echo (New-Object System.Net.WebClient^).DownloadFile($url, $output^)
    )
) 1> "%DL%"
```

Comment: thanks, that does indeed fix the issue! interesting that the open parentheses don't need to be escaped, though...